Desktop 24.04 SMB speed from debian server slower on Ubuntu than on existing windows 10 2.5g NIC
rog strix e gaming x570
RTL8125 2.5GbE nic realtek
amd 9 5950x
Although slower than 2.5, verified ISP speeds with speed-test. checked to make sure os is reporting correct NIC speeds available
Windows 10 Installed on primary NVME and i installed Ubuntu on the other NVME which was being used for games. I can still boot into windows 10 and get 270MB transfers from file server and back, however, Ubuntu is only transferring at 110MB.
I have installed smbclient and set tweaks learned on this forum and other forums that still do not work.
when prompting for the smbclient version i get Version 4.19.5-Ubuntu so manually installing the client did nothing as it is still defaulting to the built in service
any help would be much appreciated
Thanks,
